# How to update form data in database with and without updating image using php, mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

Below code is to update form details in database. It would update database only if image is changed/upload amother image. What should be done if we don't want to upload new image but need to update other form details? Thanks for solution, in advance!!!

```
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Update the Contact Record</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cms_style.css">    
<script>

window.onunload = function(){ window.opener.location.reload(); };

</script>


    </head>

    <body>
        <h2 align="center">Update the Record</h2>

    <?php

        // error_reporting(~E_NOTICE);


            //echo "Test 1 <br>";
            $cid = $_GET['id'];
            $uid = $_GET['uid'];

        /*  echo "<br> value of Con ID is : "; echo $cid;
            echo "<br> value of UID is : "; echo $uid;  */



        if($uid==1) {
            //echo "<br> Test 2 ";
            updateRecord($cid);



        } else if (isset($_GET['id']) ) {
            //echo "<br>Test 3 ";

            $ResumeID = $_GET['id']; 
            $sql="SELECT * from data WHERE ResumeID=$ResumeID";
            $result = mysql_query($sql);
            $Row=mysql_fetch_row($result); 


    ?>  
            <form align="center" action="updateRecord.php?id=<? echo "$Row[0]"?>&uid=1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <table align="center">
                    <input type="hidden" name="resumeid" value="<? echo "$Row[0]"?>">

                <!--    <? echo "<tr> <td> Resume ID </td>   <td>$Row[0]</td> </tr>" ?>  -->                     

                    <div align="center">
                        <tr>       
                            <td> Name of the Candidate</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="NameoftheCandidate" size="25" value="<? echo "$Row[1]" ?>"></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>TelephoneNo</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="TelephoneNo" size="25" value="<? echo "$Row[2]"?>"></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>       
                            <td>Email</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="Email" size="25" value="<? echo "$Row[3]"?>"></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>WEYears</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="WEYears" size="25" value="<? echo "$Row[4]"?>"></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>CurrentLocation</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="CurrentLocation" size="25" value="<? echo "$Row[5]"?>"></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>PreferredLocation</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="PreferredLocation" size="25" value="<? echo "$Row[6]"?>"></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>CurrentEmployer</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="CurrentEmployer" size="25" value="<? echo "$Row[7]"?>"></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>CurrentDesignation</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="CurrentDesignation" size="25" value="<? echo "$Row[8]"?>"></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>AnnualSalary</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="AnnualSalary" size="25" value="<? echo "$Row[9]"?>"></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>UGCourse</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="UGCourse" size="25" value="<? echo "$Row[10]"?>"></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td> Image:
                            <? echo $Row[12]; ?> </td>

                        </tr>

                        <tr>

                            <? echo '<td><img src="http://localhost/cmsapp_latest/processimage.php?id=' . $Row[0] . '"></td>';   ?>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                        <td><input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10000000" />Change Image:</td>
                        <td><input name="userfile" type="file" /></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td align="center"><input type="submit" name="submitvalue" value="UPDATE" ></td>
                            <td align="center"><input type="button" name="cancelvalue" value="CANCEL" onClick="self.close(); return false;"></td>
                        </tr>



                    </div>                              
                </table>
            </form>




    <?php
        } // end of else if

    function updateRecord($cid) {

        $msg = "Intial Value";
        $maxsize = 10000000; //set to approx 10 MB





                        if($_FILES['userfile']['error']== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
                            echo "Print uplod error - ";
                            echo UPLOAD_ERR_OK;

                            //check whether file is uploaded with HTTP POST
                            if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']))   {  

                            echo "tEST 02 - ";
                                //checks size of uploaded image on server side
                                if( $_FILES['userfile']['size'] < $maxsize) {  

                                   $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME);




                                   if(strpos(finfo_file($finfo, $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']),"image")===0)     {  

                                    echo "tEST 03 - ";

                                        // prepare the image for insertion
                                         $imgData =addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']));

                                    $sql= "UPDATE data SET NameoftheCandidate=\"$_POST[NameoftheCandidate]\", TelephoneNo='$_POST[TelephoneNo]', Email='$_POST[Email]', WEYears='$_POST[WEYears]',CurrentLocation='$_POST[CurrentLocation]', PreferredLocation='$_POST[PreferredLocation]', CurrentEmployer=\"$_POST[CurrentEmployer]\", CurrentDesignation='$_POST[CurrentDesignation]', AnnualSalary='$_POST[AnnualSalary]', UGCourse=\"$_POST[UGCourse]\", image=\"{$imgData}\", name=\"{$_FILES['userfile']['name']}\" WHERE ResumeID=$_GET[id]";

                                    //echo $sql;

                                    //$result = mysql_query($sql);  

                                    if(mysql_query($sql))

                                     echo "Record updated";

                                    else
                                        echo "Record update failed";

                                    }
                                    else
                                        $msg="<p>Uploaded file is not an image.</p>";


                                }








                                 else {
                                    // if the file is not less than the maximum allowed, print an error
                                    $msg='<div>File exceeds the Maximum File limit</div>
                                    <div>Maximum File limit is '.$maxsize.' bytes</div>
                                    <div>File '.$_FILES['userfile']['name'].' is '.$_FILES['userfile']['size'].
                                    ' bytes</div><hr />';
                                    }
                            }
                            else
                                $msg="File not uploaded successfully.";

                        }
                        else {

                            $msg= file_upload_error_message($_FILES['userfile']['error']);

                        }
                        return $msg;









        } // end of update function


    function file_upload_error_message($error_code) {
        switch ($error_code) {
            case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
                return 'The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini';
            case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:
                return 'The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form';
            case UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL:
                return 'The uploaded file was only partially uploaded';
            case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:
                return 'No file was uploaded';
            case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR:
                return 'Missing a temporary folder';
            case UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE:
                return 'Failed to write file to disk';
            case UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION:
                return 'File upload stopped by extension';
            default:
                return 'Unknown upload error';
        }




    } 


    ?>



    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Include below code in your php script

```
if ($_FILES["userfile"]["error"] == 0)
{
//update database code goes here

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a hidden field for old image and populate with the value from database in your form.

```
$image=$_FILES["NEW-IMAGE-FIELD"]["name"];

if($image!="") {

           SCRIPT TO UPLOAD NEW IMAGE
                   SCRIPT TO REMOVE OLD IMAGE
        }
    else
    {
        $image = $_REQUEST["HIDDEN-OLD-IMAGE-FIELD"];
    }
    $query = UPDATE DATABASE DETAIL WITH image='$image'";
```

Comment: please write your full code so future readers will get help.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have done solution for this.Just add below code before
             if($_FILES['userfile']['error']== UPLOAD_ERR_OK)

```
         if($_FILES['userfile']['error']== UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE)
    {
        //echo UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE;

        SQL update query      
        //echo $sql;

        if(mysql_query($sql))

                         echo "Record updated";

                    else
                        echo "Record update failed";

    }
```